# Autotools: flags for specific sub directory

Tags: autotools

In our C project which is managed by autotools we have the following (high level) directory structure:

```
<project>
 +--- configure.ac    1024 bytes
 +--- Makefile.am     1024 bytes
 +--- include         <DIR>
   +--- Makefile.am   1023 bytes
 +---source           <DIR>
   +--- Makefile.am   1022 bytes
 +--- 3rdparty        <DIR>
   +--- Makefile.am   1021 bytes
```

The 3rdparty directory contains source code which is not written by us, but regardless is compiled and linked into the main application. Unfortunately this directory contains a lot of compile time warnings, we don't want to fix.

How can I disable the warnings (with the `-w` flag) for all source files in the 3rdparty and its sub-directories?

Comment: Who is the author of `3rdparty/Makefile.am`? To which project does it belong?

Comment: @rubicks it just has a `SUBDIRS` entry for a lot of other sub directories hostingvarious libraries. Some of those are written by our colleagues, some by other developers.

Comment: that doesn't really answer my question. Regardless, if you own `3rdparty/Makefile.am`, then add the necessary `-Wno-something` flags to `AM_CFLAGS` within that file. If your project does not own `3rdparty/Makefile.am`, then either patch it and/or add the patched version to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@fritzone, to disable warnings in a third-party project is difficult. To ignore those warnings while using *much stricter* compiler flags in your own project can be done like this:

https://github.com/rubicks/autotool-subdirs

tldr; `3rdparty/Makefile.am` uses default warnings; `src/Makefile.am` uses really strict warnings (treated as errors) and uses `-isystem` (rather than `-I`) to add the `3rdparty` inclusion path.

The project should look familiar:

```
.
├── 3rdparty
│   ├── Makefile.am
│   ├── third.c
│   └── third.h
├── Makefile.am
├── autosub-top.h
├── configure.ac
├── include
│   ├── Makefile.am
│   └── autosub.h
└── src
    ├── Makefile.am
    ├── autosub.c
    └── prog.c
```

`3rdparty/third.h` contains warn-able stuff like

```
static const size_t answer = -42;
```

which is included by `src/autosub.c`. `src/Makefile.am` compiles `src/autosub.c` with

```
AM_CFLAGS =        \
  -Wall            \
  -Wconversion     \
  -Werror          \
  -Wextra          \
  -pedantic-errors \
  -std=c99
```

and links in `libthird.la`